# how to fix Es-lint "no-return-assign" for the following line of code

Tags: javascript, eslint, arrow-functions

This code runs correctly *(converting an array of objects into an object of objects)*

ES-lint however gives this error:

> [eslint] Arrow function should not return assignment.
>   (no-return-assign)

Please how may this be re-written to satisfy es-lint

```
var x = arr.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item.userid] = item, obj), {})
```

Comment: This seems like an ESLint bug. It's not returning the assignment, because of the comma operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I like code to be a bit more verbose, because one-liners look very clever *today*, but next week when I have to come back and fix a bug in that very same place, it will take me a while to understand what I was doing, not to mention if it's someone else who has to fix it.

This is how I would write it:

```
var x = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.userid] = item;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

---

Here you have a snippet with some dummy data to test it.

```js
var arr = [
        {userid: 11},
        {userid: 12},
        {userid: 13},
        {userid: 14},
    ];

var x = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.userid] = item;
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Good one! Let's try to let the machine do the computational work instead of trying to do it in our mind ;)

Comment: as a follow up question, is there any ES6 syntax or function that can directly convert an array of objects to an object of objects?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu You mean a resulting object using the array indexes as keys? For example `[{userid: 11}, {userid: 12}]` converted to `{0: {userid: 11}, 1: {userid:12}}`

Comment: no, i mean achieving the same as the code in my example, but possibly with a simplified syntax or alternative ES6 implementation. Essentially like `Array.ToObjects` or its equivalent if it exists

Comment: No, the way to do it is with a reducer. Maybe you can achieve that using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Object.assign`

```
var x = arr.reduce((obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, {[item. userid]: item}), {})
```